# Create new columns for a dataframe by parsing column values and populate new columns with values from another column python

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I need to add new columns to a dataframe based on lists within a certain column. The new columns need to be a set derived from all the lists in the column.

I then have another column with lists corresponding to the first but the data is slightly different. I need these values to populate the new columns if the values are not in a "do not include" list

Here is an example:

```
     Disease                             Status
0    Asthma|ARD                          Ph II|Ph I
1    Arthritis|Inflammation|Asthma       Ph III|Approved|No development reported
```

This should become:

```
    Disease                        Status                             Asthma        ARD        Arthritis       Inflammation
0   Asthma|ARD                     Ph II|Ph  I                        Ph II         Ph I
1   Arthritis|Inflammation|Asthma  Ph III|Approved|No development                              Ph III          Approved
```

Where here the list of "do not include" would just be ['No development'] however there are more terms I would like to include here.

The dataframe I am working with has many columns, I am interested in developing a function in which I can simply pass the df, column names, and a "do not inlcude" list that will perform this task in an efficient way (ideally without any or very few loops).

My current approach has been to create a set from the Disease columns, add it to the dataframe through pd.concat, and then loop through each row, split values in the two columns and then loop through the "Disease" list to put the correct status in the disease column.

The problem with this is that my data frame is ~12k rows, and this becomes exceptionally time intensive.

Comment: Where is your attempt to implement this, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Updated with current approach. I can't seem to dig up the exact code at the moment, can try to tomorrow. Problem is that it is not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple values in each individual cell (from your previous and current questions). It would be far far easier to tidy up your data first and then continue with your analysis. Try to put each value in each column in its own cell.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[col].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True) for col in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output of `df1`

```
              0                        1
0        Asthma                    Ph II
0           ARD                     Ph I
1     Arthritis                   Ph III
1  Inflammation                 Approved
1        Asthma  No development reported
```

And then you can pivot this from here and select only the columns you care about

```
cols = ['Asthma', 'ARD']
df2 = df1.reset_index().pivot(index='index',columns=0, values=1)[cols]
```

Output of `df2`

```
0                       Asthma   ARD
index
0                        Ph II  Ph I
1      No development reported  None
```

Then just concatenate this DataFrame to your original

```
pd.concat((df, df2),axis=1)

                             Disease                                   Status  \
index
0                         Asthma|ARD                               Ph II|Ph I
1      Arthritis|Inflammation|Asthma  Ph III|Approved|No development reported

                        Asthma   ARD
index
0                        Ph II  Ph I
1      No development reported  None
```

Comment: I've implemented this solution, but I keep running into the error:

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I'm not sure what is causing this as the above approach works for large subsets of my dataframe. Any helpful thoughts?

Comment: @wingsoficarus116 You probably have duplicate diseases for each index (Asthma appearing twice for index 0 or something like that). Please run the following code, the highest value should be 1. If it's not that is a problem. `df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 0]).count().sort_values(1, ascending=False)`

Comment: I added `print(temp_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0), 0]).count().sort_values(1, ascending=False))` but this gives me a: `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'labels'` In general I shouldn't have an entry that has "Asthma" twice in it (i.e. same index), though the series will have "Asmtha" at multiple indexes

Comment: Transparently, I have 3 instances of what you describe. I concatenated the 'index' column and the 0 column and checked the len of the original and the len of the set of the data. I'll look more into it, but is there a standard way to overcome such issues?

Comment: Issue resolved, ID'ed duplicate indexes and dropped from the df, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

- make exclusion list a `set`
- `str.extractall` was a style choice.  `str.split` will be faster
- `query` to get rid of things not to include
- `join`

---

```
dont_include = set(['No development'])

d1 = df.stack().str.extractall('([^|]+)')[0].unstack(1) \
       .reset_index(1, drop=True).query('Status not in @dont_include') \
       .set_index('Disease', append=1).Status.unstack().fillna('')

df.join(d1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to implement this version as well, but I keep getting:

AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 1554 columns

Why might this be?